# Removing the decimals of the ticks

Tags: plotting

I am adding an additional tick to a plot. How can I make the new added tick (the blue number) to have less decimal numbers? It seems "WorkingPrecision" doesn't work.

```
gamma2 = .265; gamma1 = .484; z2 = 32000/1000; zbar2 = 46200/1000;
h4 = .301; h3 = .404; h2 = .25;
h1 = .045;
h21 = h2/(h2 + h3);
h31 = h3/(h2 + h3);
p2 = 4.92;
g2 = 0.44;

Cost4 = h21 (g2 (zbar2 - z2) - g2 a p2 zbar2 gamma2 (1/(1 - τ1)));
Gain4 = h21 ((zbar2 - z2) - zbar2 gamma2 (τ1/(1 - τ1)));


daSol = Solve[{Cost4 == Gain4}, {τ1}, WorkingPrecision -> 3] // 
    Flatten // Last;
sol[aa_] := daSol /. a -> aa
yTicksToAdd1 = {N[τ1, 2] /. sol[0.05]};


d4 = Show[
  Plot[Evaluate@Table[Cost4, {a, {0, 0.05}}], {τ1, -1, 1}], 
  Plot[Evaluate@Table[ Gain4, {a, {0.05}}], {τ1, -1, 1}, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Dashed] ]]

NRm3 = Show[d4, 
  bzz = Ticks -> {Join[
      Last[Ticks /. 
        AbsoluteOptions[d4]], {#, Style[#, {Blue, 13}]} & /@ (N[
         yTicksToAdd1, 2])], Last[Ticks /. AbsoluteOptions[d4]]}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
text = Graphics[
   Text[Style[ToString[SetPrecision[yTicksToAdd1[[1]], 2]], 15, 
     Blue], {0.6, -2}]];
Show[d4, text, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-5, 10}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Epilog` to put any extra object inside a plot.

```
Show[Plot[Evaluate@Table[Cost4, {a, {0, 0.05}}], {τ1, -1, 1}], 
     Plot[Evaluate@Table[Gain4, {a, {0.05}}], {τ1, -1, 1}, 
       PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Dashed]], PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-0.5, 2.5}},
     Epilog -> {Blue, PointSize[Large], Point[{yTicksToAdd1[[1]], 0.}],
                Text[NumberForm[yTicksToAdd1[[1]], 2], {yTicksToAdd1[[1]] + 0.1, 0.}]}]
```

[image]

You can use `Style` to change the appearance of your text.